# Spinner: как обрезать текст в выпадающем списке/ добавлять в выбранный элемент?

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

Есть задача: в спиннере отображать **"Сортировать: по популярности"**, а в выпадающем списке должно быть просто **"по популярности"**, **"по возрастанию цены"**,...

**Текст в spinner не должен обрезаться**

Выглядеть должно так (**не должно обрезаться**)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при открытии должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, добавленный текст "Сортировать: " в моём случае обрезается в спиннере.

```
spinnerListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (view != null){
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnner_item_text);
                tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title_for_spinner_sort, tv.getText().toString()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

**Но spinner не учитывает добавленный текст в элемент и не изменяет ширину под новое значение**

Как можно решить проблему? Может через кастомный адаптер для спиннера? В массиве всем значениям добавить текст "Сортировать: ", а в адаптере его просто вырезать? или сделать кастомный spinner? или может, есть другой способ?

Пробовал:

прибить к спиннеру в макете отдельный textView, этот текущий способ, в кастомном адаптере удалять текст "Сортировать: "(здесь наверное я ошибся с реализацией), также давал спиннеру padding, margin.. помогло только minWidth="220dp", но это костыль. **Если есть пример, как это сделать через adapter, был бы очень признателен**

Как в кастомном адаптере это реализовать правильно, не знаю

```
    public class CustomArrayAdapter<CharSequence> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


        public CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
             super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хак, чтобы пересчитывать ширину спиннера каждый раз при выборе элемента:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (view != null){
        TextView tv = (TextView) view;

        String text = "Sort by: " + tv.getText().toString();
        tv.setText(text);

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(tv.getTextSize());
        textPaint.measureText(text);
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int width = bounds.width();

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = parent.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width + 90;
        parent.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

`params.width = width + 90;` "90" здесь - примерное значение для отступа для стрелки спиннера. Лучше указать значение в dimens.xml в dp. Стандартный размер стрелки быстро найти не удалось.

Comment: работает, благодарю!